# some users cannot access g++ include directories

Tags: g++

I am trying to compile a c++ program using g++.  When I do it as root, it's all good.  When I do it as another user (who has some fairly restricted access), I get:

fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

The code itself is just

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{}
```

So basically it does nothing, since it won't compile if it's more complicated.  Any ideas?

A few things to mention:

When I run a very basic program (just the last two lines, no includes etc), I get g++-5: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found compilation terminated

Ubuntu version is 16.04, 64 bit, server.

which g++ gives /usr/bin/g++

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this "fairly restricted access" is?

Comment: Honestly, I'm afraid that I can't.  I'm not sure how to check the permissions that each user has.  However, if I run ls -l in the include directory, everyone has at least read permissions.  I should also mention that when I use the -L flag and a link to the include directory where iostream lives, the code will still not compile.  Sorry for the vagueness!

Comment: The include file search path is modified by the `-I` flag; the `-L` is for library linkage only. You could also [edit] your question to include the output of the following command `g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null`.

Comment: oh, thanks for that info.  I changed it to -I and it still won't find it.   The output of that command for this user is # 1 "" # 1 "" # 1 "" # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4 # 1 "" 2 # 1 "" # 1 "", which looks like an error to me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output there - it's hard to read/parse in comments. Also add the outputs of `which g++` and `g++ --version`. Thanks. Also - what Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Edited.  g++ --version gives 5.3.1 20160413

Comment: Check (using `type g++` for example) that your user doesn't have `g++` aliased to something like `g++ -nostdinc++`

Comment: Hm, no aliasing.  I've narrowed the problem down to a liblto_plugin.so problem.  I'll ask another question to keep it on topic.